# Unable to use cgo CFLAGS

Tags: go, cflags

I have manually cloned the go directory of tensorflow(a library I am working on ) in  `/home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go` you can take a look [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/go/tensorflow/contrib/go). 
I have made changes to [lib.go](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/go/tensorflow/contrib/go/lib.go) as

```
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -ltensorflow
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I /home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow
// #cgo CXXFLAGS: -I /home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow -std=c++11
```

But I am getting the error

```
# github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go
In file included from go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/tf_session_helper.cc:20:0:
go/src/github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go/tf_session_helper.h:22:49: fatal error: tensorflow/core/public/tensor_c_api.h: No such file or directory
 #include "tensorflow/core/public/tensor_c_api.h"
                                                 ^
compilation terminated.
```

on doing

```
go get github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow/contrib/go
```

I am not able to understand why this is not working.

Comment: If you have to edit the CFLAGS, it's likely because you're using an outdated version of Go

Answer (score 1):

Likely a mistake with the include path, one tensorflow too many? Perhaps you should do

```
// #cgo CFLAGS: -I /home/arafat/go/src/github.com/tensorflow
```

or

```
#include "core/public/tensor_c_api.h"
```